# Slow results from cfstoredproc

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a SP which run in 0.01-0.03 sec in management studio (SQl server 2008). There are many other SP too which runs in similar time frame. While the other SP also returns almost similar number of records (varying from 10 to 500 rows) they show execution time between 0-15ms under CF debugging info, but this one SP shows execution time between 500ms-5000ms. What could be wrong?

This is how SP is being called from CF:

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="dbo.Some_Proc" datasource="#SomeDSN#" blockfactor="100">
  <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@FirstParam" value="#Variables.value1#" cfsqltye="cf_sql_numeric"> 
  <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@SecondParam" value="#Variables.value2#" cfsqltye="cf_sql_numeric"> 
  <cfprocresult name="qryResult">
</cfstoredproc>
```

This returns about 30 columns and upto 500 rows. It used to work alright till few days ago. It still runs smooth in DB, but CF call takes more time.

Comment: Could be anything.  You didn't provide enough information.

Comment: I really didn't thought that any other information could be useful. Around 6-7 SP are called from the page. All are doing  good except this one. One difference which I found was # of columns. This SP returns about 30 cols while the other have less.

Comment: Did you look at the execution plan of the sql for that sp?

Comment: Yep. I checked with DBA too. SP is fully optimized and as I wrote in question, it runs in 0.01-0.03 sec by itself. Problem is when it is called by cfstoredproc, it takes minimum of half second and sometime upto 5 seconds. I drop & recreated the SP, thinking may be execution plan has been corrupted but no difference with that as well.

Comment: Provide some code. How are you calling the proc? Are you using cfqueryparam?

Comment: Are other queries run before the SP or other SP's that run first?  It sounds like a table scan is taking place.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that could be causing the issue.  I would suggest using something such as FusionReactor to monitor the call while it is running.

Also, make sure that your database connection is set up to maintain connections, that can make a major difference.

One other thing that you might want to look at that people sometimes overlook is to make sure that when you connect to SQL Server using SSMS that you use the same login and password that ColdFusion is using.  Sometimes security settings can be different and can make a difference (an admin login can get more priority than a limited login).

Adding the version of ColdFusion might be helpful at troubleshooting.

Finally, cf911.com has a lot of resources for troubleshooting and CF in general.